# Xamarin Forms android ToolbarItem on left

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, custom-renderer

There are plenty of options & custom renderers available to move a Xamarin Forms toolbar item with Priority = 0 to left side of the navigation bar in iOS, could someone point me to a an approach for the same on Android.

On a high level, I understand we will need to do this using a custom renderer of the Navigation page, but I don't have a very good idea of what needs to go in this renderer on android to achieve this.

Any help is apprenticed.

Thanks